# Determine which vectors belong to a column space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

$$
{}A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2\\ 1&1&1\\ -1&2&5\end{bmatrix}
$$

*Determine which vectors belong to a column space*

a) (0,1,-1)

b) (1,0,3)

c) (-1,0,1)

d) (-1,1,2)

e) (0,0,0)

f) (1,1,1)

If we start with the concepts found in the task. So if we look at the matrix A, then a column is 0, 1, 1, aSo the first column. The vector that makes up (0, 1, -1) is a column. A column space is all linear combinations of the column vectors in a matrix. A is just the matrix we start from. The column space consists of a lot of linear combinations.

So if a vector (in this case called u) can be written as a sum, where the terms consist of a constant multiplied by a vector, then u is a linear combination of the vectors included in the sum!. So this is about understanding what a colon room is in order to understand the question. So the column space consists of all linear combinations (vectors) that can be created from our vectors k1, k2 and k3. For example. create a vector belonging to this column space (a linear combination of k1, k2 and k3).

Combine the column vectors of matrix A, multiply them by whatever you want, and then add them together. Then you get a new vector. This vector is a linear combination of k1, k2 and k3. and is thus included in the column space of A.

I cannot chooe any vectors, but must use the column vectors in the matrix A, i.e. named k1, k2 and k3. But the coefficient in front of the vectors (i.e. 0, 2 and -1) can be chosen as one likes! (real numbers)

But I'm not sure how to solve the problem with the information above. This is my attempt:

The columns of A are the following:

$$
    c_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\ -1\end{bmatrix} ,\  c_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 2\end{bmatrix} ,\  c_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\ 1\\ 5\end{bmatrix}
$$

a) Yes, this vector belong to the column space since that's just c₁.

b) Here it's just c₂ - c₁

For c), we want to convert them to simultaneous equations, so we want x,y,z such that:

y+2z = -1

x+y+z = 0

-x+2y+5z = 1

x, y, z will then be the coefficients of c₁, c₂, and c₃, respectively. They won’t be unique as if x = 1, y = -2, z = 3 works, then so will x = 2, y = -4, z = 6, for example.

Comment: You can check that $\det A = 0$ so the matrix is not invertible (which would make the rest of the problem easy). Trial & error (notice the $(1,1)$ entry is zero) shows that $c_3 = 2 c_2 -c_1$, so we can just work with the first two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint based on @copper.hat comment.

Replace the third column with the column vectors a) to f). If the determinant of the $3\times 3$ you get each time is $0$ the vector is in the column space. If it is not $0$ it is not in there.

Comment: Nice approach. ${}$

Comment: I made an edit to my post, could you give me your feedback on what I added?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that $\det A = 0$ so the matrix is not invertible (which would make the rest of the problem easy).

Trial & error (notice the $(1,1)$ entry is zero) shows that $c_3 = 2 c_2 -c_1$, so we can just work with the first two columns. So, the problem is for each vector $v$ above, find $k_1, k_2$ such that $v = k_1 c_1 + k_2 v_2$.

Since the $(1,1)$ entry is zero in this case, this tells you immediately what $k_2$ must be, then see if there is a $k_1$ that works. If there is then that is the solution, if not, then $v$ does not lie in the column space.

Comment: I made an edit to my post, could you give me your feedback on what I added?